# Async storage in React Native could not store functions inside Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

Storing Objects such as:

```
Foo = {
a: 'a',
b: 'b',
bar: function() {
        alert("done");
    }
}
```

I am using following code snippet:

```
try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('sometoken', Foo)
  } catch (e) {
    // save error
  }
```

It Does save the object without any errors thrown in catch block, but while retrieving the item, returns only:

```
Foo = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b'
    }
```

I am using getItem to retrieve the data

What am I missing here?

Comment: AsyncStorage can store only strings. Besides, there's no `alert` function in React Native

Comment: Objects have to be serialized before they can be stored. Functions cannot be easily serialized because they are more than just a string that makes up the code. Functions are part of a lexical scope, once you put it in storage that same environment wouldn't exist anymore.

Comment: Instead, you'll want a function that deserializes a Foo. Ie, a function that takes `{a:'a',b:'b'}` and returns a Foo.